# WordPress don't show older posts

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

Trying to not show older posts in a query_posts() function but it doesn't appear to be working. I need to not show posts past the current date and only show ones yet to happen. I'm using the publish date to set the values in the admin side but I get get the query to work.

current code is:

```
<?php $args = array( 
                                        'order_by'      => 'date', 
                                        'order'         => 'ASC', 
                                        'year'          => date('Y'),                         
                                        'monthnum'      => date('m'),                       
                                        'day'           => date('d') 
                                        ); ?>
                    <?php query_posts( $args ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's covered, right [in the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters). Example:

```
$today = getdate();
$args = array(
    'post_status' => 'pending',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => array(
            'year'  => $today['year'],
            'month' => $today['mon'],
            'day'   => $today['mday'],
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```